# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'. > jarMerging

Tags: android

I'm getting this error:
`Multidex and ccid.jar are not used at the same time.` When I removed `ccid.jar`, it works.

```
dependencies 
    {
        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
        compile files('libs/akiscif-2.4.7.jar')
        compile files('libs/asn1rt-6.5.3.jar')
        compile files('libs/ccid-1.1.5.jar')
    }
```

**Error**

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
> java.io.IOException: Can't read [D:\workspace android_studio\EDenetiS\app\build\intermediates\transforms\jarMerging\debug\jars\1\1f\combined.jar] (Can't process class [com/scdroid/ccid/c.class] (Unknown verification type [29] in stack map frame))
```